# Add, set, get item into hashtable

Tags: powershell

I want a hashtable like this :

```
$myHash = @{ 
   "key1" = @{
       "Entry 1" = "one"
       "Entry 2" = "two"
   }
   "key 2" = @{
       "Entry 1" = "three"
       "Entry 2" = "four"
   }
}
```

How can I add multiple value into a hashtable (like this) :

```
$myHash = @{}
$myHash .Add("key", value1, value2)
```

=> don't work

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$myHash = @{}
$myHash .Add("key", @{value1=value2})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myHash = @{}
$myHash.Add("key",("one","two"))
$myHash
```

The output is something like:

```
Name                           Value                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                 
key                            {one, two}
```